# Installing tradingWithPython module - ImportError: No module named 'lib.functions'

Tags: python, module

I am a complete noob so please do take pity. Have searched for the answer to my problem for a few hours now, and am making no progress. I'm using the Anaconda3 32bit Windows version of IPython 3.4 (notebook)

I want to install the tradingWithPython module, using !pip install tradingWithPython. It seems to be looking for the functions.py file in the lib folder (which is there) but it doesn't find it. This is what I get:

Collecting tradingWithPython

Using cached tradingWithPython-0.0.14.0.zip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8doxz5zd\tradingWithPython\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tradingWithPython as twp

  File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8doxz5zd\tradingWithPython\tradingWithPython\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lib.functions import *

ImportError: No module named 'lib.functions'

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8doxz5zd\tradingWithPython\setup.py", line 3, in <module>

    import tradingWithPython as twp

  File "C:\Users\Gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8doxz5zd\tradingWithPython\tradingWithPython\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>

    from lib.functions import *

ImportError: No module named 'lib.functions'
```

What am I missing? I have also tried to install from the cmd line but with the same result. And I have a Python 2.7 version which gives me the same result.

thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Module have written for python 2.7 and it should install correctly. Just check python version for sure.

If you want to run module in Anaconda based on python 3.x, you should do next steps:

- Unzip tradingWithPython-0.0.14.0.zip
- Run "Anaconda Command Prompt"
- In command prompt write:

  ```
  cd %path_to_unzipped_folder%/tradingWithPython-0.0.14.0
  2to3 -w -n --no-diffs .
  ```
- Done.

Run

```
python setup.py install
```

to install package.